# How to extract string separated by comma with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, recursion, preg-match, pcre

I need extract a string separated by comma or comma and space.
Example:

```
<?php
    //regexp
    $regexp = "/(select\s+(?<name>[a-z0-9]+)\s+(?<values>[^\d]+[a-z0-9]+\s*(\s*,|\s*$)))/";
    //text
    $text = "select this string1,string_2,string_3 ,string_4, string5,string_6";
    //prepare
    $match = array();
    preg_match( $regexp , $text , $match );
    //print
    var_dump( $match);
?>
```

I created this regexp:

```
(?<values>[^\d]+[a-z0-9]+\s*(\s*,|\s*$))
```

But this does not work perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: explode() or str_getcsv() and then array_walk the resulting array with a callback of `trim`

Comment: `explode(',',  $text)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use something like `~(?|select ([^\W_]+) | *([^\W,]+) *,?)`, if you want to check that you obtain only alphanumeric characters. Example:

```
$subject = 'select this string1,string_2,string_3 ,string_4, string5,string_6';
$pattern = '~(?|select ([a-z][^\W_]*+) | *+([a-z][^\W,_]*+) *+,?)~i';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

if (isset($matches[1])) {
    $name = array_shift($matches[1]);
    $strings = $matches[1];
}
```

Or another way:

```
$pattern = '~select \K[a-z][^\W_]*+| *+\K[a-z][^\W,]*+(?= *,?)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

if (isset($matches[0])) {
    $name = array_shift($matches[0]);
    $strings = $matches[0];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for this:

```
$text = "select this string1,string_2,string_3 ,string_4, string5,string_6";
$stringArray = preg_split("/,\s*/",$text);
```

But it would be much easier to just split after each comma and then trim the result:

```
$stringArray = explode(",",$text);
```

Comment: this does not work, i need string with "a-z0-9_", no "·$%&/(/&%$·xxfr\x45" :(
Thanks!

Comment: @OlafErlandsen you can use explode first, than you process the strings