# Comma delimited strings match and separately with regex (find and replace / preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a list:

`cat, dog, duck`

I want to get the words from this list and store them separately. so:

`cat`
`dog`
`duck`

I tried this regex but it doesn't work properly for me: ([^,]+)
*https://www.regextester.com/108606*

The problem is that I don't get the words, I just get the commas, this: `,,`

It would be needed for software that works in a php-based preg_replace way. Here's how I used it:

> Find: ([^,]+)
>
> Replace: *leave empty*

Can you help me with the right regex that gets the words separately from the comma-separated list and stores them separately? I searched the internet (I didn’t get it) but couldn’t find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried just using `explode(",", $string)`?

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work because the software only has a "find:" and "replace:" field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract string separated by comma with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570763/how-to-extract-string-separated-by-comma-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this,

#### 1:

```
$str = 'cat, dog, duck';
$splitted = preg_split('~(,\s*)~', $str);

var_export($splitted);
```

Checkout: [preg-split()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

#### 2:

```
$str = 'cat, dog, duck';

$split = explode(',', $str);
$split = array_map( // Removes Starting Whitespace
    function($v) {
        return ltrim($v);
    }, $split); 

var_export($split);
```

Checkout: [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php),

All of them also removes the spaces after `,`. So, You get exact output as desired.

Output,

```
array (
  0 => 'cat',
  1 => 'dog',
  2 => 'duck',
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work because the software only has a "find:" and "replace:" field.